# Mutators in blockly

Tags: javascript, mutators, blockly

I'm adapting nmap API to Blocks programming using Blockly. I'm trying to create a mutator to write methods like: cassandra.describe_cluster_name(socket,cassinc) and I need the inputs to be dynamic. I can't reuse code from the demo because I can't understand it even when I've read the documentation 200 times, everything I've tried results in no block showed in the toolbox. Can anyone explain me how can I write a mutator to do that? I'm very lost and I can't do it in the easy way: making a block with two inputs and add it in recursively till I don't need more inputs. I declare all of my blocks in JSON. Very very thank you.